# How to filter out certain patterns from mocha/nyc test coverage (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, nyc

In mocha.opts, I am sure how to set-up coverage pattern that needs to be taken into account but not sure how to include the patterns that has to be filtered-out?

For example,

I have the file `mocha.opts` containing coverage patterns which is passed as param to the following command: 
`nyc mocha --opts ./mocha.opts`

The content of the `mocha.opts` is given below:
`test/tests/routes/*.test.js`

But there are lot of `custom js scripts` imported into *.test.js files. But these `custom js scripts` contains functions which I don't want to be covered under coverage report nor I have written unit test for them. 
Is there any way to filter out these patterns from coverage by declaring them into `mocha.opts` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In package.json, you can add nyc configuration. Something like this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc#excluding-files

```
"nyc": {
  "include": [
    "./**/*.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./test/",
    "./db/migrations/"
  ]
}
```

I haven't seen a way to specify in mocha.opts though.